# SVG: Unexpected pixel in stroke-dasharray at start corner of rect

Tags: svg, stroke-dasharray

I'd like to draw a rectangle with a top and bottom border (as part of a [database-flow diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_diagram)). Therefore, I use stroke-dasharray on rect like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="-64 -24 178 73" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect stroke-dasharray="50 25" width="50" height="25" fill="none"
          stroke="black"></rect>
    <text x="25" y="13" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central"
          font-size="10px" fill="#414141">Database
    </text>
</svg>
```

If you look closely at the top left corner of the rendered rectangle, you should see a notch (highlighted by the magenta circle). This pixel is not rendered in the other corners of the rectangle (highlighted by the green vertical line):

[image: rendered PNG]

I expect

- no notch
- that the top line has the same length as the bottom line
- that the top and bottom line start at the same x-position in the rendered image

That means, I expect the image to look like this (without the magenta circle and green line)

[image: fixed image]

How to fix my SVG to look like this? Can this be done with `stroke` on `rect`?  Why is the notch/pixel added in the first place?

---

**Edit:** I have this issue on Linux in Google Chrome Version 95.0.4638.69 and Firefox 94.0, but it seems to be a bug (see [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70054459/svg-unexpected-pixel-in-stroke-dasharray-at-start-corner-of-rect/70057358#comment123837368_70054459)).

Comment: Why not just use two lines?

Comment: That seems to be a firefox bug - looks fine on Chrome latest/Win10

Comment: @MichaelMullany I have this issue on Linux in Google Chrome Version 95.0.4638.69 and Firefox 94.0, but not in Google Chrome on Android. So I guess, you are right that it is a bug and not intended.

Comment: @RobertLongson I actually wanted to understand the cause of the issue (intended behavior), but it seems to be a bug.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Thank you for pointing this out. I can confirm that it looks fine on Windows 10 in Google Chrome Version 95.0.4638.69 and Version 96.0.4664.45

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a firefox bug- looks fine in Chrome/Win. If you convert your rect to a path, it works fine.

```html
<svg viewBox="-64 -24 178 73" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 0 0 h50 v 25 h-50 v-25" stroke-dasharray="50 25" fill="none"
          stroke="black"></path>
    <text x="25" y="13" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central"
          font-size="10px" fill="#414141">Database
    </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

[@MichaelMullany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271353/michael-mullany) has given a workaround.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/70054910/1065654). Alternatively, you can use `stroke-linecap="square"` to extend the line and cover the notch

```html
<svg viewBox="-64 -24 178 73" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect stroke-dasharray="50 25" width="50" height="25" fill="none"
          stroke="black" stroke-linecap="square"></rect>
    <text x="25" y="13" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central"
          font-size="10px" fill="#414141">Database
    </text>
</svg>
```

Tested with Google Chrome Version 95.0.4638.69 on Linux.